# implementing Prime-factor FFT algorithm

Tags: fft, python, dft

I've been trying for days to implement this algorithm to work with size N samples but I can't manage to do it. my goal is to compute FFT for 100 samples, so I need factor 5 and 2, I wrote a simple FFT function and a prime factor function but I don't really understand how to go beyond that and articles with complex math aren't helping..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def prime_factor(n):
    """
    prime factorization
    """
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors

def fft(x):
    """
    FFT algorithm
    """
    N = len(x)
    if N <= 1:
        return x
    else:
        even = fft(x[0::2])
        odd =  fft(x[1::2])
        T = [np.exp(-2j*np.pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in range(N//2)]
        return [even[k] + T[k] for k in range(N//2)] + \
               [even[k] - T[k] for k in range(N//2)]

def main():
    """
    main function
    """
    x = np.random.rand(100)
    y = fft(x)
    plt.plot(y)
   
main()
```

**UPDATE: Bob solution and my the final Radix-5 implementation:**

```
import numpy as np

def fft(x):
    """
    radix-2,3,5 FFT algorithm
    """
    N = len(x)
    if N <= 1:
        return x
    elif N % 2 == 0:
        # For multiples of 2 this formula works
        even = fft(x[0::2])
        odd =  fft(x[1::2])
        T = [np.exp(-2j*np.pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in range(N//2)]
        return [even[k] + T[k] for k in range(N//2)] + \
               [even[k] - T[k] for k in range(N//2)]
    elif N % 3 == 0:
        # Optional, implementing factor 3 decimation
        p0 = fft(x[0::3])
        p1 = fft(x[1::3])
        p2 = fft(x[2::3])
        # This will construct the output output without the simplifications
        # you can do explorint symmetry
        return [p0[k % (N//3)] +
                p1[k % (N//3)] * np.exp(-2j*np.pi*k/N) + 
                p2[k % (N//3)] * np.exp(-4j*np.pi*k/N)
               for k in range(N)]
    elif N % 5 == 0:
        # Here you must implement the factor 5 decimation
        # start following the template for the factor 3 implementation given above
        p0 = fft(x[0::5])
        p1 = fft(x[1::5])
        p2 = fft(x[2::5])
        p3 = fft(x[3::5])
        p4 = fft(x[4::5])

        return [p0[k % (N//5)] +
                p1[k % (N//5)] * np.exp(-2j*np.pi*k/N) + 
                p2[k % (N//5)] * np.exp(-4j*np.pi*k/N) + 
                p3[k % (N//5)] * np.exp(-6j*np.pi*k/N) +
                p4[k % (N//5)] * np.exp(-8j*np.pi*k/N)
               for k in range(N)]

x = np.random.rand(100) # 2 * 2 * 5 * 5
print(np.allclose(fft(x), np.fft.fft(x)))
```

Comment: And you aren't going to use `numpy.fft` because why?

Comment: Because I actually need to implement this in CPP, the function itself, I would LOVE to use numpy otherwise

Comment: And you are not going to use fftw or some other existing C, C++, or Fortran-based math package because why?  It's not that I'm averse to helping, but it's 2021: aside from self-learning or super-reliable systems, you need strong reasons to not use pre-made math packages for things like this.

Comment: I 100% agree with you, my professor told me it's better if I implement it myself that way I can learn.. I dived abit into this and it's super complicated, I'm going to give it few lasts try before I head over to FFTW

Comment: Writing for a quirky platform is one reason to either roll your own, or modifying some generic open source implementation. Having done it once is great knowledge and skill to carry in your toolbelt even if you may not ever do it again. Just like everyone should try to write assembler at least once.

Comment: I actually need to perform FFT on 100 samples, you don't need a Prime factor algorithm if you think about that, however I thought if I already implementing this why not make it generic to work with every N size of FFT, but now I see it's much more complicated

Comment: yeah, long story short: either, this is homework to get you to research and debug and learn how to debug and develop a FFT yourself, in which case I honestly think we'll be doing you a disservice, or **by far** the fastest solution to this problem is implementing the DFT as simple vector-Matrix product. The math in your python application takes a very tiny fraction of the time – it's the python interpreting that takes 99% of time. Doing it in a single product will be way, way, way faster than jumping around, checking conditionals in multiple loops of different lengths and so on.

Comment: So, if your job is to "implement the Fastest Fourier Transform you can do in pure Python", then, yeah, you fail because you're trying to be smart. Actually, you're no taht spart, you're trying to compute exponentials on the go, and that's the main thing that the "proper" FFT typically saves you.

Comment: so, also, if you're trying to implement a classical split-prime FFT in Python, then you're not doing too well (but I'd also respectfully point out to your professor that that is like trying to compete in formula one with a container ship and makes no sense at all. If you need to do it to learn how to do it, do it in a compiled language where tight loops actually are fast. FFT in Python itself: just won't happen.

Comment: However, you write **Articles with complex math aren't helping...**: Well, guess why your professor gave you this homework: It's not about implementing a fast Fourier transform **at all**. You have a professor, which means you're writing some kind of thesis on signal processing, and complex math still irritates you: you need to get behind that. Being able to work on this until you solve this, **on your own** was the whole point of giving you this assignment. If you have problems with that, I **strongly** recommend making an appointment with your professor and asking them well-prepared …

Comment: … questions. It's their job to help you – and they clearly want you to succeed if this is the assignment you've gotten! So, they will try and help you (or point you to an assistant who can help you) if you put in the work and now have questions. You seem to have put in quite some work in your code, so do prepare good, precise questions you can ask your professor, and ask them!

Comment: It ***does*** seem odd to me that a professor would give an assignment to code an FFT routine, ostensibly to teach students how it's done and ***not*** make it a simple radix 2.

Comment: Well, it's not really a professor but a mentor, I have a project I'm working on and he said that it's better if I implement most of the code myself instead of using libraries, I did implement a FFT Radix-2 algorithm but he recently told me that I need a prime algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you are doing only the radix-2 decimation, that splits the input vectors (the inverse of interleaving), and then concatenate the results. Notice that they user the fact that $e^{-1j\pi}=-1$ to do only $N/2$ multiplications instead of $N$. Maybe this simplification made more difficult to see the link from this to the general formula.

Here I give you an implementation of the radix-2,3 FFT, the radix-3 decimation is left without without simplification. I hope from this you can write the radix-5 decimation more easily.

Code

````
import numpy as np

def fft(x):
    """
    radix-2,3 FFT algorithm
    """
    N = len(x)
    if N <= 1:
        return x
    elif N % 2 == 0:
        # For multiples of 2 this formula works
        even = fft(x[0::2])
        odd =  fft(x[1::2])
        T = [np.exp(-2j*np.pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in range(N//2)]
        return [even[k] + T[k] for k in range(N//2)] + \
               [even[k] - T[k] for k in range(N//2)]
    elif N % 3 == 0:
        # Optional, implementing factor 3 decimation
        p0 = fft(x[0::3])
        p1 = fft(x[1::3])
        p2 = fft(x[2::3])
        # This will construct the output output without the simplifications
        # you can do explorint symmetry
        return [p0[k % (N//3)] +
                p1[k % (N//3)] * np.exp(-2j*np.pi*k/N) + 
                p2[k % (N//3)] * np.exp(-4j*np.pi*k/N)
               for k in range(N)]
    elif N % 5 == 0:
        # Here you must implement the factor 5 decimation
        # start following the template for the factor 3 implementation given above
        raise NotImplementedError("5-factor decimation not given")

x = np.random.rand(36) # 2 * 2 * 3 * 3
assert(np.allclose(fft(x), np.fft.fft(x)))

```
````

Comment: Thank you so much, that clearly showed me how exactly I need decimate, I think I managed to implement the factor 5 decimation, I added it to my post if you want to see but it seems like it works :)